# Arranging divs using css tables

Tags: html, css

I have 4 `div` elements and I need to arrange the first two in one row and the next two in the second row.The `div` elements are being being generated in a loop so can't access each individually.So, I tried using `:nth-child` property but can't work it out.Here is an example of the code. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ma1vmbvc/)

HTML

```
<div class="relatedposts">
 <div class="relatedthumb">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/120/60" ><br>
        <p>Post to check the page builder plugin</p>
 </div>
 <div class="relatedthumb">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/120/60" ><br>
        <p>Post to check the page builder plugin and now the second line here ok
 </div>
 <div class="relatedthumb">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/120/60" ><br>
        <p>Post to check the page builder plugin</p>
 </div>
 <div class="relatedthumb">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/120/60" ><br>
        <p>Post to check the page builder plugindskjnfkdjndskjcndskjcndsk
 </div>
```

CSS

```
    .relatedposts{display:table;}
.relatedthumb {
display: inline-block;
    width:40%;
}
.relatedthumb img{text-align:center;}
div.relatedthumb:nth-child(2n+1){
    display:table-row;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need CSS tables for this.

I've [updated your code to use floats & clear](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/4mjv3m5k/2/) instead of CSS tables:

```
.relatedposts {
    display:table; 
}
.relatedthumb {
    width:40%;
    float: left;
}
.relatedthumb img {
    text-align:center;
}
div.relatedthumb:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: This is working but the divs that are in a row loose their alignment when the height of one div increases

Answer (score 1):

You just assigned the CSS property to the wrong div. Assign it to the parent div and it works.

```
div.relatedposts:nth-child(2n+1){
    display:table-row;
}
```

Comment: But I need the divs in one row to be aligned to each other even when height of one div is greater than the other

Comment: Then set `vertical-align:top` for the relatedthumb divs. That will line things up along the top of the container, rather than the bottom as they are now.